# Windows 7 Network printer is not saved

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

I installed a samsung clx printer, connected it to my switch.
I set the printer to have static ip, all definitions are OK.
On windows i go to "Device and printers" and click "Add a printer"
After it finds my printer i can print via word etc.
My problem starts when i restart the computer or after sleep, the printer appears as not available. but it is connected to network. other people can see her and print with her. If i want to print i need to discover and re-add her as a printer.

Why is this ?
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main culprit is **windows 7 fails to start printer spooler services at startup.**

**Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Services.**

Find the item **Print Spooler** and right-click. Set it to **start automatically** and hit OK, then reboot.

Hope it works...

Comment: it is already started, my problem is that the computer looses the printer as active printer and i see it as offline although it is connected properly

Comment: you can turn SNMP off on the printer driver/properties and it will work..... try it ... its a issue related to windows 7

Comment: Go to the ports tab in the printer properties and click configure port.
untick the SNMP Status Enabled option